# No API credentials when adding test accounts

Tags: api, paypal, credentials, missing-features

No end of trouble since the developer site and sandbox was changed last week. I've not managed to make a single working call to the new platform since it was launched.

I've managed to get as far as getting 100002 errors back - which at least means things are talking, but I noticed today that if I create test accounts, the API Credentials are blank/missing:

![screenshot])(http://qikr.co/files/pics/p/paypalnoap91044.jpg)

Does anyone know a fix for this? I've cleared out the browser cache etc.

Comment: You might want to add a description and/or a tag explaining _what_ API you’re actually talking about. (One could _guess_ that you mean PayPal from the image – but a solid question should not require guessing.)

Comment: My bad - the link from the Paypal development area took me right here - so I assumed that was a given.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the Credentials not appearing for some accounts. Currently you are logged into the developer account. Try logging into the actual sandbox seller account, and going to the profile and requesting the credentials. You should be able to view these from within the Sandbox seller account, and if they have not been requested yet, you can generate these.

Log out Paypal account
clearing browser cache and cookies (I use firefox).
Go to developer.paypal.com and login with the real paypal account (not the Sandbox one)
Go to Applications
Click on Sandbox accounts
(Optional) Import your old accounts from your former Sandbox account after the redirect to the accounts page
Click on the account you want to log in to
Choose Sandbox site
Log in to that site using your test business account
Go to My Profile
In Account information click on Request API Credentials
Choose the option that solves your needs
The API crecendiales were created !!! (they will appear in your test account profile)

Comment: I hit a problem with that. When you create the account in the developer area, you specify the card/bank account/balance options. These are not transferred either.

So even though this may allow me to get the API data I need, I still can't test because of a zero balance on the buyer account!

What an update - this really got broken badly. 2 weeks of non development since the changes, now is a great time to look for another gateway solution.

Comment: And an additional problem - when requesting API details I'm greeted with:

"Please confirm your email address before requesting an API certificate"

Trying that gives the expected result:
"A confirmation email has been sent to this address. Please confirm this email address by clicking on the link in the email."

But that email never arrives. No sign of it in the server logs - no connection from Paypal seen anywhere.

Comment: Try logging into the actual sandbox buyer account, and going to the profile of that account and add a credit card/bank account.  This will then allow you to use this account for making purchases on the sandbox.  As for confirming the email address, you should of received an email to your sandbox email account that you access from the developer.paypal.com.  You can confirm the email here.  Otherwise if you can give me the merchant id or test sandbox email address (not your developer acct email, or your live email address)for your account, I can confirm it from my end.

Comment: If I try to add a bank account, it wants credentials and an account number - naturally I don't want to provide good info, and I don't have a note of what it used on the old preconfigured accounts.

I tried, also, to add card - using a list of Paypal test card numbers found here:

http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

That didn't work either - it rejects with "We're sorry, but that credit card can't be linked to additional PayPal accounts. Please link a different credit card" on every card I try.

No sign of the confirm email BTW

Comment: Also tried deleting the accounts and starting again - but after hitting delete I'm taken to:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts/delete

which comes up with a tomcat 404 screen.

This is well and truly broke! Wow, not good.

Comment: Some of the issues have been corrected on some of our boxes, so you may want to try clearing cookies and cache and recreating the accounts.  It's hit or miss right now, depending on which box you hit.  However if you hit one of the boxes that has been fixed, you should be able to successfully set up a working account.

Comment: What's the ETA for a full fix chad?

Comment: I do not have an ETA as to when the issues will be completely resolved.  As for the credit card numbers I can provide you with a list of card numbers to try using.  The list you referenced earlier is for Payflow.  Try one of these numbers.  4929090468906343
4929440455998615
4916740797687312
4929735770379247
4539981632429117

Comment: This morning I've been able to access the API credentials after walking away from it for a few days. The problem now is attempting a basic NVP call with Curl (which used to work fine on the old system) generates this:

"You do not have permissions to make this API call"

I'm at my wits end with this. How can a company the size of Paypal take a perfectly good working system and destroy it? Who ever did this needs to be fired.

Comment: DUMP:
{ ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(20) "2013-03-25T07:39:35Z" ["CORRELATIONID"]=> string(13) "44d5564bc4099" ["ACK"]=> string(7) "Failure" ["VERSION"]=> string(8) "0.000000" ["BUILD"]=> string(7) "5479129" ["L_ERRORCODE0"]=> string(5) "10002" ["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]=> string(35) "Authentication/Authorization Failed" ["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]=> string(49) "You do not have permissions to make this API call" ["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]=> string(5) "Error" }

Comment: This error is typically caused due to a few reasons, either the API credentials that you are passing over are not correct or your passing over a variable called "SUBJECT" in your API call where you are populating it with an email address of a PayPal account you are trying to process a payment on.  I dont see the subject being passed over, and you are hitting the sandbox.  Try verifying the credentials that you are using.  If they are correct and you still get the error, can you provide the full API request that you are sending and I will test with it to see what the issue is.